# Elasticsearch -- count number of keyword occurences in a document

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Database: Elasticsearch v7.2 
Application: Laravel v5.7 
Using Elasticsearch/Elasticsearch (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) Official PHP Library

I have a query_string query for Elasticsearch with this code to retrieve documents that have a certain phrase as I search throughout my index

```
[
    "query_string" => [
        "default_field" => $content,
        "query" => $keywords
    ]
],
```

and the `$keywords` variable contains:

```
("MCU" OR "Marvel" OR "Spiderman")
```

Now, I want to count the **NUMBER OF OCCURENCES** of these words in the documents that I'm about to retrieve

I used the aggs query with this:

```
'aggs' => [
    'count' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'content.keyword'
        ]
    ]
]
```

However, I have no idea how to associate these `doc_count` and display it in a matched manner with the hits -- because the key itself is the content, instead of the IDs

[image]

Im planning to display the whole document and pertain how many times the `$keywords` above have occurred in each document as `Mentions`

[image]
Is there other way to do the counting of occurrences without using the `aggs` in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to sir @AshrafulIslam, I was able to come up with Elasticsearch's feature called `highlights`. Though `highlights` literally emphasizes keywords that occur, I resorted to PHP's `substr_count()` function to count the `<em>` tags

I added this code as a sibling of the `['body']['query']` element:

```
"highlight" => [
    "fields" => [
        "content" => ["number_of_fragments" => 0]
    ],
    'require_field_match' => false
]
```

Then as I loop through the `['hits']['hits']` array element, I performed something like this:

```
$articles = $client->search($params);
$hits = $articles['hits']['hits'];

for($i=0; $i<count($hits); $i++){
    $hits[$i]['_source']['count_mentions'] = substr_count($hits[$i]['highlight']['content'][0],"<em>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you only wants to count the occurrences of keywords, then you don't have to enable fielddata, try the filters aggs along with your query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "content", 
      "query": "MCU OR Marvel OR Spiderman"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "mcu": {
            "match": {
              "content": "MCU"
            }
          },
          "marvel": {
            "match": {
              "content": "Marvel"
            }
          },
          "spiderman": {
            "match": {
              "content": "Spiderman"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result with be like below :

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1.219939,
    "hits": [
      ....
      ....
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "count": {
      "buckets": {
        "marvel": {
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        "mcu": {
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        "spiderman": {
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html

Comment: hello sir, is there a way to count the number of occurrences of my `$keywords` in the documents (specifically with the **CONTENT** field) without using the `aggs`?

Comment: @JueViole17 Updated the answer, added new approach to count only the number of  occurrences of the keywords

Comment: sir @AshrafulIslam thank you for the helpful update of your response, appreciate it! However, my `$keywords` variable is dynamic -- in the sense that in my PHP application, every other user that logs in, will change the contents of `$keywords`, because `$keywords` are according to the logged in user...

should I change your answer into : 
`"mcu": {
            "match": {
              "content": $keywords
            }
          }`

Comment: @JueViole17 If you put the keywords into the match query then it will be same as total hits count. Instead for each keyword build the filters query with format `"$keyword": { "match": { "content": $keyword } }`

Comment: hello sir @AshrafulIslam, is there a way for me to display this `count` aggs in every document? I mean for example: in Article #17: there was 3 times my `$keywords` appeared in that document's `content` field

Comment: Hello @AshrafulIslam, good day! can you think of ways to do this without using aggs?

Comment: You cloud use ElasticSearch Highlighting feature to highlight the occurrences of your search query, then count it from the PHP end.   
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Fieldata may not be the best way to enable text search.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata

> Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make sense to do so.
>
> A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like New York can be found by searching for new or for york. A terms aggregation on this field will return a new bucket and a york bucket, when you probably want a single bucket called New York.
>
> Instead, you should have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword field with doc_values enabled for aggregations, as follows:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```