# Require Elasticsearch highlight words enclosed with Double Quotes (") instead of chopping them

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: v7.2 
Application: PHP - Laravel v5.7

Hello and good day!

I'm developing a web application that is similar to a search engine, whereas a user will enter words that will be designated to the variable `$keywords`. Then I have this query to search throughout my index:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type'  => 'my_type',
    'from'  => 0,
    'size'  => 10,
    'body'  => [
        "query" => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        "query_string" => [
                            "fields" => ['title','content'],
                            "query" => $keywords
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$articles = $client->search($params);
```

Now, in line with my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932330/elasticsearch-count-number-of-keyword-occurences-in-a-document), I was able to count the number of occurrences my `$keywords` occurred within the documents of my index.

Here's my `highlight` query that is attached to the `$params` above:

```
"highlight" => [
    "fields" => [
        "content" => ["number_of_fragments" => 0],
        "title" => ["number_of_fragments" => 0]
    ]
    'require_field_match' => true
]
```

Even though that the `$keywords` are enclosed with double quotation mark ("), the `highlighter` still chops/separates the `$keywords` and I already specified them with double quotation mark to strictly follow these `words`.

For example, my $keywords contains `"Ayala Alabang"`, but as I displayed the output, it goes like this

[image: Sample Output]

The `$keywords` were separated, but according to the output, they're just adjacent to each other.

Is there any other tweaks or revision to my query? I found some related posts or questions in some forums, their last reply was from March 2019, any advice would be an excellent help for this dilemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of looking into deep documentation, I found a way to properly segregate keywords that are found in a document

**STEP 1**

Apply the `"explain" => true` in your `$params`

```
$params = [
            'index' = "myIndex",
            'type'  => "myType",
            'size'  => 50,
            'explain' => true,
            'query' => [
                'match_all' => [
                    //your elasticearch query here
                ]
            ]
]
```

**STEP 2**

Then fetch the result after doing the `$client->search($params)` code:

```
$result = $client->search($params);
```

Then a long literal **EXPLANATION** will be included in your `$result` whereas your `keywords` and their `frequency` will be displayed in a text format.:

```
try displaying via dd($result['explanation'])
```

**NOTE** the problem here is that a lot of nested arrays will be the contents of the `_explanation` array key, so we came up with a recursive function to look for the `keywords` and their `frequency`

**STEP 3**

You need to create a function that will get a string **IN BETWEEN** of repetitive or other strings:

```
public static function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

**STEP 4**

Then create the recursive function:

```
public static function extract_kwds($expln,$kwds)
{
    foreach($expln as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($k == 'description' && strpos(json_encode($v),'weight(')!==false)
        {
            if(isset($kwds[$this->get_string_between($v,':',')')]))
            {
                $kwds[$this->get_string_between($v,':',')')] += intVal($this->get_string_between($expln['details'][0]['description'],'score(freq=',')'));
            }
            else
            {
                $kwds[$this->get_string_between($v,':',')')] = intVal($this->get_string_between($expln['details'][0]['description'],'score(freq=',')'));
            }
        }
        if($k == 'details' && count($v) != 0)
        {
            foreach($v as $k2=>$v2)
            {
                $kwds = $this->extract_kwds($v2,$kwds);
            }
        }
    }
    return $kwds;
}
```

**FINALLY**

I was able to fetch all the `keywords` together with their `frequency` or how many times these `keywords` appeared in the documents.